# How to properly setup VS2008 for x64 programing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, 64-bit

On x64 win7, I installed VS2008 and x64 compile tools. I was testing it with a simple "hello world" console program. Both x86 and x64 versions were compiled flawless. Both Debug and Release subversions of the x86 version works fine. The release x64 version works fine too. However, the Debug x64 version always raises the side-by-side error. It seems like the debug runtime cannot be found.

Someone suggest to install the Debug runtime redist. That surprises me: does the x64 debug runtime should already come with the VS2008 installation as the x86 version?

Thanks a lot!

@sj1900 "Some of the x64 compiler components are optional on a VS installation. It's worth checking that they have all been installed."
here is the screenshots:
[image: VS2008 components]

I did not see any further options here. There is no amd64_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt in the winSxS at all. Strange problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a debug runtime redistributable.  I believe that the debug runtimes only come with the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of head scratching and testing, I finally reckon that is a VS2008 installer bug, confirmed by several online references.

If one installed the vs2008 **without** the x64 compiler tool **at the first time** but installed the x64 tools **later** via the modification feature of the installer, the bug will show up: all the x64 debug runtimes and the nodebug openMP runtime will be missing. Reinstall will not fix this problem.

I tried lots of methods suggested all over the internet: install all the hotfixes, ATL updates, update to SP1 or install the VCredist ... Nothing works.

I figured out there are two ways to fix this:

1. uninstall the VS2008 completely then install the VS2008 again as fresh with the x64 tools selected.
2. this will be annoying for some person who installed lots of hotfixes. The most straightforward way is to **build a installer to install all those missing runtimes**: `create porject->other projects->setup project`. Then `add&Merge Module` -> select all the missing runtimes: `Microsoft_VC90_OpenMP_x86_x64.msm` , `Microsoft_VC90_DebugOpenMP_x86_x64.msm` and `Microsoft_VC90_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm`.
   Build and release the solution, run the installer, then go to `%windir%\winsxs`, you should happily see all those runtime folders. Then you can start to debug your x64 programs.
   If u are using VS2008SP1, then u probably get another error about the runtime version. To avoid this, install the ATL update for SP1 before u start to create the installer.

PS: there are lots of other annoying but not fatal bugs in VS2008 which the M$ never bother to fix. Thus stay away from VS2008 and try VS2010, unless your projects have the special need that forces you to stick to VC9.

Comment: This is an extremely helpful answer. For unknown reasons (shared workstation) I ended up with "side-by-side configuration is incorrect" due to missing winsxs manifest files for the "9.0.30729.6161" DebugCRT. The solution #2 to create a "Merge Module" installer for DebugCRT worked perfectly. (this was for debugging *on my own computer*, not for redistribution, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the x64 compiler components are optional on a VS installation.  It's worth checking that they have all been installed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. As I mentioned I do have the x64 compiler tools installed. This is actually a bug of the VS2008 installer. So I cannot accept ur answer.